# Solve $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}(1-x)=\cos^{-1}x$ and avoid extra solutions while squaring

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, radicals, inverse-function

Solve the equation,

> $$
> \sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}(1-x)=\cos^{-1}x
> $$

**My Attempt:**
$$
\cos\Big[ \sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}(1-x) \Big]=x\\
\cos\big(\sin^{-1}x\big)\cos\big(\sin^{-1}(1-x)\big)-\sin\big(\sin^{-1}x\big)\sin\big(\sin^{-1}(1-x)\big)=x\\
\sqrt{1-x^2}.\sqrt{2x-x^2}-x.(1-x)=x\\
\sqrt{2x-x^2-2x^3+x^4}=2x-x^2\\
\sqrt{x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x}=\sqrt{4x^2-4x^3+x^4}\\
x(2x^2-5x+2)=0\\
\implies x=0\quad or \quad x=2\quad or \quad x=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Actual solutions exclude $x=2$.ie, solutions are $x=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
I think additional solutions are added because of the squaring of the term $2x-x^2$ in the steps.

So, how do you solve it avoiding the extra solutions in similar problems ?

**Note:** I dont want to substitute the solutions to find the wrong ones.

Comment: If you square an equation, you can make sure you don't have extraneous solutions simply by plugging in all the values you found and discarding the ones that don't solve the equation.

Comment: The addition equation $x =2$ didn't come from squaring $2x-x^2$.  I think it came from evaluating $\cos(sin^{-1}(1-x)$ as $\sqrt {2x - x^2}$.  I think.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip that is the most obvious thing to do. but, question was how to avoid extra solutions without doing it.

Comment: @ss1729 I realize it's obvious, but it's a perfectly valid method, and I wanted to make sure people realized that. The main issue here is that when you square, you are proving a forward implication, whereas you really need an iff. But the fact that you have a forward implication is enough to show that the set of correct solutions is a subset of the ones you find.

Comment: @ss1729 I changed my display name so it didn't seem like my comment was negative. :)

Comment: Taking cosine can also introduce invalid solutions. Whenever you apply a non-injective function to both sides of an equation, this can happen. And it's quite common, and perfectly valid, to only check in the end by plugging solutions into the original equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain gives
$$-1\leq x\leq1$$ and $$-1\leq1-x\leq1,$$ which gives $$0\leq x\leq1,$$
which says that the answer is $$\left\{\frac{1}{2},0\right\}.$$
I think it's better after your third step to write
$$\sqrt{2x-x^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ or $x=0$.

Comment: thnx. i didnt think that way. though i am always afraid of squaring while solving such equations.

Comment: Just remember that $x^2=y^2\Leftrightarrow x=y$ for $xy\geq0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to avoid the extraneous solution.  Note that $\arcsin u+\arccos u={\pi\over2}$ for all $u\in[-1,1]$. Thus we can rewrite $\arcsin x+\arcsin(1-x)=\arccos x$ as

$$\arcsin x+{\pi\over2}-\arccos(1-x)={\pi\over2}-\arcsin x$$

which simplifies to

$$2\arcsin x=\arccos(1-x)$$

Applying $\cos$ to each side and using $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2\theta$, we get $1-2x^2=1-x$, or

$$2x^2-x=0$$

which has $x=0$ and $x={1\over2}$ as its only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Barry Cipra,

$$2\arcsin x=\arccos(1-x)$$

Now $0\le\arccos(1-x)\le\pi$ and $-\pi\le2\arcsin x\le\pi$

$\implies\arcsin x\ge0\iff x\ge0$

Now for $\arcsin x\ge0,2\arcsin x=\begin{cases}\arccos(1-2x^2)&\mbox{if }x\ge0\\ 
-\arccos(1-2x^2)& \mbox{if }x<0\end{cases}$

$x\ge0\implies 1-x=1-2x^2$

Can you take it from here?